# How can I change a rendered user display to a combination of fields linking to the user?

Tags: 7, users

I have a set of users on the site I'm building that have First and Last name fields in their profile.  How can I create a display that will show the user link as "Last name value, First name value" all inline?

There are a number of places where this is how I want user references to show up.  In some other places, it would be ideal to show those fields, and a couple of others along with the user's image.  Then of course there is the full profile view.  I had though this must be done with different display types, but can not see anyway to bring fields inline with each other, or adjust what text makes up the link.

Comment: so instead of the user name you want to display last name and first name?

Comment: @NoSssweat exactly

Comment: ok... how are you going about this? Views or Template file?

Comment: Template files right now.

Comment: [How to rewrite output of a field in D7](https://www.drupal.org/node/1285272)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to use **[hook_username_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_username_alter/7)**

then in your **template.php** file located in `/sites/all/themes/yourtheme`

add the following code:

```
function yourtheme_username_alter(&$name, $account) {
  if (isset($account->uid)) {
    $this_user = user_load($account->uid);//loads the custom fields
    $name = $this_user->field_first_name['und'][0]['value'].' '.$this_user->field_last_name['und'][0]['value'];
  }
}
```

replace **yourtheme** with your actual theme name.

You might not want to alter the user name when you're in the user profile page. So you could do something like this:

```
function yourtheme_username_alter(&$name, $account) {
if (    arg(0) != 'user' // test if you are on user page
) {
  if (isset($account->uid)) {
    $this_user = user_load($account->uid);//loads the custom fields
    $name = $this_user->field_firstname['und'][0]['value'].' '.$this_user->field_lastname['und'][0]['value'];
       }
     }
}
```

replace **yourtheme** with your actual theme name.

Comment: That is what I had read that I was trying to remember!  When I'm not stuck in a meeting I'll try that out!

Comment: @UltraBob how did it go?

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use:

#### [Real Name](https://www.drupal.org/project/realname)

> The RealName module allows the administrator to choose fields from the
> user profile that will be used to add a "real name" element (method)
> to a user object. Hook_user is used to automatically add this to any
> user object that is loaded. It will also optionally set all nodes and
> comments to show this name.

For Example:

> [image]
>
> By default only the raw username is being shown, as you can see at the
> top of the page.
>
> [image]
>
> Change this to:
>
> [image]
>
> Result:
>
> [image]
>
> source: [Change Drupal Usernames with the Real Name Module](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/real-name-module/)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very similar to [Combine two fields to be displayed together](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/95609/combine-two-fields-to-be-displayed-together) where you'll find several ideas, some of which are solving your problem even without custom code.

Hope will help

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't found that, but I need these coming out as links to the user profile, and I need them to show up in a lot of different places, including as the rendered preview in the paragraphs module.

Comment: And I never need the link to be the user name. I'd be totally fine with editing some kind of user.tpl.php template file to do this, if there is a way to make the change for just one display type. Is display suite really the best answer for that?

Comment: @UltraBob,  I guess you should give a try to Display Suite. Once done, you'll know how good it can support your work.

Comment: the thing about that is Display Suite is gigantic.  I am trying to keep things slim, and I find it hard to believe that the best way to make user links show up in a compact form that uses some fields from the profile is to install a do-everything module.

Comment: With that said, I am going to install it and have a look.  Maybe it will solve some of my other outstanding issues.